# Run curl command on each line of a file and download the files

Tags: bash

I have a file containing a list of pdf files.

```
this is a test.pdf
this is a/another test.pdf
test number 5_ example.pdf
...
```

I know that doing: 
    curl -O "https://report2018/this is another test.pdf" 
will download the file.

So the scenario is use curl in bash script to download all the pdf's in the file one by one when the beginning of the URL should be: "https://report2018/" .

So a complete URL will be https://report2018/+PDF_NAME

Any ideas or suggestions how to do it in bash script?

Answer (score 1):

It is a pretty basic script actually...
You can break your problem in two pieces:

- Basic usage of bash, in general;
- How to cycle a file.

Something like this will suffice:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<file.list # Put the file in a file descriptor
while read -r line <&3; do # Read line by line the file descriptor
  curl -sk "https://report2018/${line}" > "${line}" # make curl and save in file
done
exec 3>&- # Close file descriptor
```

Obviously you have to change the curl with your needs (E.G. User Agent and/or authentication).

Note that with `> ${line}"` after curl, you will save the file with the same name read by `file.list`.

I hope this helps you, and please, next time, use a search engine first.